# Select statement in custom SQL Tableau based on another custom SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, tableau-api

I am creating lots of new data sources using custom SQL option in Tableau.
I want to create another new data source that will contain `Select` statement referring to another custom SQL. Example :

Tables provided in database :

1. `school`, fields including : `area`, `area_code`, `school_id`, `school_name`
2. `student`, fields including: `school_id`, `student_id`, `student_name`
3. `mark`, fields inclusing: `school_id`, `student_id`, `mark_value`

custom SQL #1, named `testresult` :

```
SELECT student.student_name, mark.mark_value,
CASE WHEN mark.mark_value > 70 THEN 'passed'
WHEN mark.mark_value BETWEEN 50 AND 60 THEN 'retake'
ELSE 'failed'
END AS student_result
FROM student
LEFT JOIN mark ON student.student_id = mark.student_id
```

custom SQL #2, named `arearesult` :

```
SELECT school.area, school.area_code, student.student_name, testresult.student_result
FROM school
LEFT JOIN student ON school.school_id = student.school_id
INNER JOIN testresult ON school.student_name = testresult.student_name
```

It all works well until I try to create custom SQL #2 `arearesult`. It seems Tableau does not recognize custom SQL as a table. Is there anyway I can do this?

Please note that because of the condition of my real data, it is only possible to do it by joining the 3 tables as I explained above, instead of using 1 SQL script. I know based on the data I provided in my example, it is possible and much easier to use 1 SQL script. But in reality I just can not do that.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do all of this using a subquery instead of CTE.

```
SELECT school.area, 
   school.area_code, 
   student.student_name, 
   testresult.student_result

FROM school
LEFT JOIN student ON school.school_id = student.school_id 
INNER JOIN (SELECT student.student_name, mark.mark_value,
              CASE WHEN mark.mark_value > 70 THEN 'passed'
                   WHEN mark.mark_value BETWEEN 50 AND 60 THEN 'retake'
                   ELSE 'failed'
                   END AS student_result
            FROM student
            LEFT JOIN mark ON student.student_id = mark.student_id) testresult ON school.student_name = testresult.student_name
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. But in reality, I have to create multiple new fields using custom SQL. What I mean by 'new field' is something like ```student_result``` in my example. So if I were to follow your answer, how and where do I put these multiple new fields in ```FROM``` statement? Also, is there any more compact solution than this?

Comment: It totally depends how complex is the sql and how many new fields you will need. Also how often will it change and if it is being used in multiple data sources in tableau. If you think your sql is complex enough and will be used multiple times in tableau and you have access rights to create objects in DB then you can just create a view in the database and access it in Tableau as "Select * from New_View"